# Xamarin.Forms Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have a ListView bound to a ObservableCollection, what im trying to do is get some user input in a View and add an Object to my Collection so my ListView gets notified.

Unfortunately my app Crashes when i add something to my Collection with the following Exception Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.This is so frustrating ive tried everything no idea why my app crashes by simple Collection Add.

ListView

```
<ListView  x:Name="lstFruits"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding FruitModel.FruitOptionModel.CurrentFruit.FruitCollection}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"
                     SeparatorVisibility="None"
                     Grid.Row="1" >
            <ListView.Behaviors>
              <commands:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding TappedCommand}" EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource ItemTappedConverter}" />
            </ListView.Behaviors>
          </ListView>
```

and im adding items with following Code:

```
FruitModel.FruitOptionModel.CurrentFruit.FruitCollection.Add(FruitObject);


<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <commands:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter x:Key="ItemTappedConverter"/>
      <local:GeräteListItemTemplateSelector x:Name="GeräteListItemTemplateSelector" x:Key="TemplateSelector" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

 public GeräteListItemTemplateSelector()
        {
            neuesGerätDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(NeuesGerätViewCell));
            gerätDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(GerätViewCell));
        }

        private readonly DataTemplate neuesGerätDataTemplate;
        private readonly DataTemplate gerätDataTemplate;

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container) {
            var gerät = item as GerätModel;
            if (gerät.NeuesGerät) {
                return neuesGerätDataTemplate;
            }
            else {
                return gerätDataTemplate;
            }
        }
```

StackTrace:

```
 at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:650 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (Boolean nonPublic) [0x000ca] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:115 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:89 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5599 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00040] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:201 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:134 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ElementTemplate+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<.ctor>b__0 () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ElementTemplate.cs:23 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ElementTemplate.CreateContent () [0x00026] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ElementTemplate.cs:78 
  at Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplateExtensions.CreateContent (Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate self, System.Object item, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject container) [0x00014] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\DataTemplateExtensions.cs:12 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].CreateContent (Int32 index, System.Object item, Boolean insert) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:527 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].ConvertContent (Int32 startingIndex, IList items, Boolean forceCreate, Boolean setIndex) [0x00014] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:664 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnProxyCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, Boolean fixWindows) [0x0017e] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:1002 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnProxyCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:954 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x0000a] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ListProxy.cs:230 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy+<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<OnCollectionChanged>b__0 () [0x00018] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ListProxy.cs:203 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.OnCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x000a0] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ListProxy.cs:222 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy+WeakNotifyProxy.OnCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00031] in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ListProxy.cs:386 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00012] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs:288 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, System.Object item, Int32 index) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs:351 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].InsertItem (Int32 index, System.Collections.ObjectModel.T item) [0x00024] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs:219 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[T].Add (System.Collections.ObjectModel.T item) [0x00023] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3412/3cf8aaed/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs:67 
  at LindeXF.ViewModels.FruitViewModel+<<get_NextButtonCommand>b__85_0>d.MoveNext () [0x00118] in C:\Users\valon\Desktop\Linde\LindeXF\LindeXamarinForms\LindeXF\LindeXF\LindeXF\ViewModels\FruitViewModel.cs:386
```

Comment: add your static resources

Comment: sure check my edit

Comment: Have you tried it without german umlauts in your variable and class names? I'm not really sure if every component can handle these.

Comment: @ValonAncilotto Try to intialize your Fruit Collection with new object

Comment: It would be great if you could upload your code in Github and share with us to help you further.